# Usage of "much" + plurals

Tags: grammar

> Too much questions

Is this correctly used or wrong?

I thought it should be many or a few.

Answer (score 2):

It should be "Too many questions" because questions is a countable noun.

Much is used with uncountable nouns, e.g. "Too much rain".

You could say "Too much questioning" - singular gerund nouns are uncountable.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a countable noun, you cannot use much.

Much > non countable nouns, as money, water, hair. 
Many > countable nouns, as car, bottle, **question**

To no wether you should use many or much, simply try to "count" the noun you are using.

Ex: you cannot say I have 3 moneys or 2 oxygens, so they must be used with **much**.

Ex: You can say I have 3 cars, 4 bottles or 2 questions, so they must be used with **many**.

As stated by you, the noun is question, as question is countable, you cannot say How much questions, you should use How **many** questions instead.

The same apply with **few**, it is used with countable nouns, on the otherhand **little** is used with non countable ones.

Comment: You certainly *can* say that you have four hairs. (Growing out of your ear, for instance.)  Idiomatically, you can also ask a waiter for "two waters" or you can order "two coffees."

Comment: Than I got tricked by all my English professors heh, I'm gonna change that, thanks ¡!